# Split rows in train test based on user id PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, train-test-split

I have a PySpark dataframe containing multiple rows for each user:

| userId | action | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | buy | 8 AM |
| 1 | buy | 9 AM |
| 1 | sell | 2 PM |
| 1 | sell | 3 PM |
| 2 | sell | 10 AM |
| 2 | buy | 11 AM |
| 2 | sell | 2 PM |
| 2 | sell | 3 PM |

My goal is to split this dataset into a training and a test set in such a way that, for each `userId`, N % of the rows are in the training set and 100-N % rows are in the test set. For example, given N=75%, the training set will be

| userId | action | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | buy | 8 AM |
| 1 | buy | 9 AM |
| 1 | sell | 2 PM |
| 2 | sell | 10 AM |
| 2 | buy | 11 AM |
| 2 | sell | 2 PM |

and the test set will be

| userId | action | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sell | 3 PM |
| 2 | sell | 3 PM |

Any suggestion? Rows are ordered according to column time and I don't think that Spark's `RandomSplit` may help as I cannot stratify the split on specific columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had similar requirement and solved it in following way:

```py
data = [
  (1, "buy"),
  (1, "buy"),
  (1, "sell"),
  (1, "sell"),
  (2, "sell"),
  (2, "buy"),
  (2, "sell"),
  (2, "sell"),
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["userId", "action"])
```

Use `Window` functionality to create serial row numbers. Also compute count of records by each `userId`. This will be helpful to compute percentage of records to filter.

```py
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, row_number
window = Window.partitionBy(df["userId"]).orderBy(df["userId"])
df_count = df.groupBy("userId").count().withColumnRenamed("userId", "userId_grp")
df = df.join(df_count, col("userId") == col("userId_grp"), "left").drop("userId_grp")
df = df.select("userId", "action", "count", row_number().over(window).alias("row_number"))

df.show()
+------+------+-----+----------+
|userId|action|count|row_number|
+------+------+-----+----------+
|     1|   buy|    4|         1|
|     1|   buy|    4|         2|
|     1|  sell|    4|         3|
|     1|  sell|    4|         4|
|     2|  sell|    4|         1|
|     2|   buy|    4|         2|
|     2|  sell|    4|         3|
|     2|  sell|    4|         4|
+------+------+-----+----------+
```

Filter training records by required percentage:

```py
n = 75
df_train = df.filter(col("row_number") <= col("count") * n / 100)
df_train.show()
+------+------+-----+----------+
|userId|action|count|row_number|
+------+------+-----+----------+
|     1|   buy|    4|         1|
|     1|   buy|    4|         2|
|     1|  sell|    4|         3|
|     2|  sell|    4|         1|
|     2|   buy|    4|         2|
|     2|  sell|    4|         3|
+------+------+-----+----------+
```

And remaining records go to the test set:

```py
df_test = df.alias("df").join(df_train.alias("tr"), (col("df.userId") == col("tr.userId")) & (col("df.row_number") == col("tr.row_number")), "leftanti")
df_test.show()
+------+------+-----+----------+
|userId|action|count|row_number|
+------+------+-----+----------+
|     1|  sell|    4|         4|
|     2|  sell|    4|         4|
+------+------+-----+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ntile`:

```
ds = ds.withColumn("tile", expr("ntile(4) over (partition by id order by id)"))
```

The dataset where `tile=4` is your test set, and `tile<4` is your train set:

```
val train = ds.filter(col("tile").equalTo(4))
val test = ds.filter(col("tile").lt(4))

test.show()
+---+------+----+----+
| id|action|time|tile|
+---+------+----+----+
|  1|  sell|3 PM|   4|
|  2|  sell|3 PM|   4|
+---+------+----+----+

train.show()
+---+------+-----+----+
| id|action| time|tile|
+---+------+-----+----+
|  1|   buy| 8 AM|   1|
|  1|   buy| 9 AM|   2|
|  1|  sell| 2 PM|   3|
|  2|  sell|10 AM|   1|
|  2|   buy|11 AM|   2|
|  2|  sell| 2 PM|   3|
+---+------+-----+----+
```

Good luck!